# Expression in stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that accepts a phrase as a condition.
I am writing reports that send parameters dynamically.

The procedure has be something like the following where the variable `@WHERE` needs to be replaced with the string I send as input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] 
    @WHERE NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM MTRL WHERE @WHERE
END
```

So execution has to be something like

```
execute TEST 'AND PRODUCT=3 AND DATE IS NULL'
```

I do not want to be explicit with variables. For example, to use

```
WHERE PRODUCT=@PRODUCT AND DATE = @DATE AND NAME LIKE '%@NAME'
```

as this is subject to change. Filters are multiple and different every time for the same report according to user selections.

The error I get when I try the generic solution is

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'.

Comment: Your proposed solution is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen. You should not do this unless you are absolutely sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, it is. Nice to mention that. Parameterized Input with Stored Procedures should be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need dynamic sql so change sp as per below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] 
   @WHERE NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    exec('SELECT * FROM MTRL WHERE 1= 1 ' + @WHERE)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to have conditions appended dynamically to where clause, because you will become vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

But if it is required you can try as following:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @sql='SELECT * FROM MTRL WHERE'+ @WHERE
execute sp_executesql @sql
```